# problem related to the Mayer-Vietoris Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $D_{k}$ be the surface obtained by removing k small 
disjoint open 2-discs from the unit disc $E^{2}$. Show that $D_{k}\simeq G_{k}$, the k-leaved rose.

Let $M_{k}$ be the surface obtained by identifying two copies of D along their boundaries. to calculate $H_{2}(M_{k})\cong R$ and $H_{1}(M_{k})\cong R\oplus\cdots\oplus R$ 2k-copies.

Comment: What is $D_k$? Is it just $D$ for some fixed $k$? Is $R$ the coefficient ring for the homology? What have you tried so far? Generally, you should show how much you've already done and where you're getting stuck.